# How to parse this JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json, exif, exiftool

I have a very simple task - I have a list of image and video files and I'll like to tabulate the creation date for each using the available EXIF data. I'm using [pyexiftool](https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool) for the actual data extraction.

I can pull the data out without a problem, but the resulting JSON output has a very strange shape. Each record has one field, but that field may contain 2 or 3 or multiple bits of information.

For example, some image files contain `XMP:CreateDate` and `EXIF:CreateDate`, whereas MOV files contain 'QuickTime:CreateDate' (I don't know what the fields would be for other file formats).

```
[{'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200422_085514.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091856.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:18:57'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091859.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0004.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:05:59'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0005.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:08:26'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0006.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:09:17'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0035.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:12 14:08:55'}]
```

I am quite lost on how to parse this file and I can't loop through it as I would a regular JSON file. I only want to extract only a filename and creation datetime. I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

**EDIT** The code that produces that 'JSON' output is this,

```
def old_main():
    dir_name = '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/'
    tags = ["File Name", "CreateDate"]
    log_file = 'py_log.txt'
    file_names = getListOfFiles(dir_name)
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as e:
        metadata = e.get_tags_batch(tags, file_names)
    with open(log_file, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(metadata, outfile)
```

So what I've pasted is the direct output of the `json.dump` method. The `get_tags_batch` method is documented [here](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/#exiftool.ExifTool.execute_json).

Unless I've misunderstood the documentation for this package, it looks like the output is not JSON at all but rather just a string?

Appreciate the pointers and comments.

Comment: This is not `JSON`. Note the single quotes, which would never be to used to define a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the snippet you posted, it is a `list` of `dict`. If the format is more complicated than that, please post a more complete example.

This is a simple way of iterating over each item and setting the date based on the first date field found.

```
results = []

for item in json_list:
    d = {'SourceFile': item['SourceFile']}
    date_keys = [k for k in item.keys() if 'CreateDate' in k]
    if date_keys:
        d['Date'] = item[date_keys[0]]
    else:
        d['Date'] = None
    results.append(d)
```

Comment: If the OP is accurate in his description, the input is coming from a file, so it is a string not a dict. But it is *not* correct `JSON` format.

Comment: Yes, I added some sample code on how I was generating the file. But I managed to figure out where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having trouble parsing this this "JSON" is because it is *not* `JSON` (note the use of single rather than double quotes). This *cannot* be parsed unmodified with a `JSON` parser.

Instead use:

```
from ast import literal_eval

t = """[{'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200422_085514.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091856.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:18:57'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091859.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0004.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:05:59'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0005.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:08:26'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0006.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:09:17'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0035.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:12 14:08:55'}]"""
o = literal_eval(t)
print(o)
```

Prints:

```
[{'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200422_085514.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:22 08:55:14'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091856.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:18:57'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/IMG_20200423_091859.JPG', 'EXIF:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00', 'XMP:CreateDate': '2020:04:23 09:19:00'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0004.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:05:59'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0005.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:08:26'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0006.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:11 13:09:17'}, {'SourceFile': '/Users/Documents/Projects/ExifData/temp/MOV_0035.mp4', 'QuickTime:CreateDate': '2017:03:12 14:08:55'}]
```

According to the manual, `literal_eval`:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None